# How to define scope while running checkstyles

Tags: svn, checkstyle

In our project we have defined checkstyles recently. So, if there is any checkstyle failure while committig code then it is not allowing to commit the code in repository. But there are failures already present in the code(which are before defining checkstyles) and we dont want to correct those failures.

Is there any option that checkstyle will run only on the changes made after a particular date. Kindly, suggest if possible.

Answer (score 2):

What I recommend in this situation is a simple plan of:

1. Collect the existing Checkstyle violations;
2. Create a suppressions file for the found violations; AND
3. Setup Checkstyle to use the [SuppressionFilter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html) to ignore the existing errors.

To collect the existing Checkstyle violations, run Checkstyle and report on the existing errors using the [XMLLogger](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/XMLLogger.html) formatter. To see how to do this with ANT, see [here](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html).

Convert the errors into a [Suppressions XML Document](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#XML_Details) and be a specific as possible on the location of each error being suppressed. This has the advantage that if somebody modifies a file, they are forced to fix existing errors. **Note:** some people then get *very creative* on how they modify files to avoid having to fix Checkstyle errors! :-)

Finally, modify the Checkstyle rule set to use the [SuppressionFilter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html). When setup correctly, running Checkstyle should no longer report any violations - except for new ones!